# Can't reproduce Hero animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I'm new in flutter and just now finished the course. Now I'm trying to create my first app and I can't reproduce Hero animation between two screens.
Sorry, I can't post all of my code, rules doesn't allow that.
Second Screen:

```
Hero(
  tag: 'HotelAvatar$indexRow',
  child: Container(
    width: 60.0,
    height: 60.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

First screen:

```
Hero(
  tag: 'hotelAvatar0',
  child: Container(
    width: 160.0,
    height: 160.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: The two widgets must have the same hero tag. Your example clearly shows your widgets don't have the same hero tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two [Hero](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Hero-class.html) widgets need to have the same exact tag for it to work. In your case you have one with upper case characters and another with lowercase characters. Correct them to be the same, and it should work as intended.

```
tag: 'HotelAvatar$indexRow',
```

```
tag: 'hotelAvatar0',
```